# Pymongo - Fastest way to query all documents

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I have a file contain nested dictionary i save on my computer, when i need that file, i used this line of code :

`u_i = pickle.load(open("F:\\ForTestCode\\user_item_21_07.p", "rb"))`

This is type data in `u_i` :

```
{"BF0E6CF26097FF44B56EBA795F25B48A" : {"557252215845" : 1.0}, 
       "9FFA99A1374CD953A30CB1F746F11C6A" : { "978076659142" : 1.0, "622" : 1.0}
               }
```

And then, i inserted nested dictionary to MongoDB, its became like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57971bcffefb610990cc5eaa"),
    "BF0E6CF26097FF44B56EBA795F25B48A" : {
        "557252215845" : 1.0
    }
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57971bcffefb610990cc5ec6"),
    "9FFA99A1374CD953A30CB1F746F11C6A" : {
        "978076659142" : 1.0,
        "622" : 1.0
    }
}
```

So, if i need put all documents in MongoDB into one file like `u_i` above i need to make a loop like this :

```
temp_dict = {}
documents_u_i = collection_u_i.find({})
for records in documents_u_i:
   for item in records:
       if item != "_id": # I dont need key and values of `_id`
           temp_dict[item] = records[item]
```

And `temp_dict` will be the nested dictionary like `u_i` above.

```
temp_dict = {"BF0E6CF26097FF44B56EBA795F25B48A" : {"557252215845" : 1.0}, 
       "9FFA99A1374CD953A30CB1F746F11C6A" : { "978076659142" : 1.0, "622" : 1.0}
               }
```

But i don't want used `for` loop cause in my db have > 90.000 documents

Is there fastest way to query data without using `for` loop ?

Thanks very much for help me !

Comment: You need to change your document structure and make all those dynamics key a field's value. Also consider to show us the expected result

Comment: In find() function i set `"_id" : False`, and its return others keys and values : `find({}, {'_id': False})`